# Converting immutable to mutable collections

Tags: scala, collections, immutability, mutable

What is the best way to convert `collection.immutable.Set` to `collection.mutable.Set`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
scala> var a=collection.mutable.Set[Int](1,2,3)                              
a: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)

scala> var b=collection.immutable.Set[Int](1,2,3)
b: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)

scala> collection.mutable.Set(b.toArray:_*)      
res0: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)

scala> collection.mutable.Set(b.toSeq:_*)  
res1: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)

scala> collection.mutable.Set(b.toList:_*)
res2: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Out of the three, which is better?

Comment: This is one of the top Scala annoyances no doubt.

Answer (score 12):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, via factory builders applied with [`.to(factory)`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/Set.html#to[C1](factory:scala.collection.Factory[A,C1]):C1):

```
Set(1, 2, 3).to(collection.mutable.Set)
// collection.mutable.Set[Int] = HashSet(1, 2, 3)
```

Prior to `Scala 2.13` and starting `Scala 2.10`:

```
Set(1, 2, 3).to[collection.mutable.Set]
// collection.mutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)
```